# React-Native-Vision-Camera Exception when reading a QR-Code

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I'm using react-native-vision-camera to build a QR-Code-Scanner for my app. I followed this guide by dynamsoft: https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/react-native-qr-code-scanner-vision-camera.html

In the beginning everything worked fine but now I'm always getting an Exception when reading QR-Codes with my camera. **Even with the provided example project in the post it's not working properly anymore.**

The detected result I get always has asterisks in it like this: `[Attention(exceptionCode:-20111)] *ttp*//**ca*h*st*9*02/*entalobje*ts*book**98420*d*6b**-4***-9e***6*d796*0c*55`

I already tried reinstalling the library and everything but I can't get it to work.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I have been trying to resolve. For me this issue pops up only in ios build. Followed the exact same guide, examples, etc. Please do share the solution if you are able to find any.

Comment: @RahulThampi will do!

Comment: Hey @Tim Langner, this seems like a License expiry issue from `DynamsoftBarcodeReader` [Error List](https://www.dynamsoft.com/license-server/docs/common/errorlist.html?ver=latest)

Comment: Hi @RahulThampi thanks for letting me know! I'll look into your answer in more detail tomorrow and let you know if it helps me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[vision-camera-dynamsoft-barcode-reader](https://github.com/xulihang/vision-camera-dynamsoft-barcode-reader) has an internal dependency on [DynamsoftBarcodeReader SDK](https://www.dynamsoft.com/store/dynamsoft-barcode-reader/) and it needs an active license, which I found out in their other examples. In all their examples, public license are used which has an expiration date.

Due to this reason, I made a switch to [vision-camera-code-scanner](https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-code-scanner). This was already suggested in [Community Plugin List](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processor-plugin-list#plugin-list) of [VisionCamera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera).

Hope this helps!